# Difficulty of removing the apostrophe in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to remove apostrophes, below is the whole procedure.

```
BEGIN
SET _myparam = replace(_myparam, "'", '');
UPDATE `Table` SET NAME=_myparam WHERE UID=_someotherparam;
END
```

I also tried:

```
SET _myparam = replace(_myparam, '\'', '');
SET _myparam = replace(_myparam, '''', ''); 
SET _myparam = replace(_myparam, CHAR(39), '');
SET _myparam = replace(_myparam, '%\'%', '');
```

This seems to work with any other character but not the apostrophe. Nothing here seems to remove the apostrophe character. Any help would be appreciated.

I Googled everything I could think of, and have been pulling out hair for hours. Thanks!

Comment: Generally for most RDBMSs you have to use a `SELECT` statement with the `SET` assignment.  You generally can't just set a variable to be equal to a function like you show here.

Comment: @BaconBits it actually works fine like that in MySQL. You can use `DECLARE <variablename>` to init the variable then `SET <variablename> = blah()`

Comment: @wired00 Ah, good to know.  I'm used to T-SQL style (MS SQL, Sybase) and PL/SQL style (Informix, Oracle, Postgres) so I tend to assume an RDBMS will follow one of those two styles.  Most of them do, IMX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this standard select out and it works. have you just tried

`'\''` ?

ie, this works in standard select:

```
SELECT REPLACE("hi th'ere", '\'', '');
```

this does not:

```
SELECT REPLACE("hi th'ere",'%\'%', '');
```

of course this also works:

```
SELECT REPLACE("hi th'ere","'", '');
```

**Edit:** Here is the solution as MySQL Stored Procedure.

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE TestStoredProc(IN _myvariable VARCHAR(25)) 
BEGIN
SET _myvariable = REPLACE(_myvariable, '\'', '');
SELECT _myvariable;
END // 
DELIMITER ;
```

and

```
CALL TestStoredProc("hi th'ere");
```

Comment: tried '\'' isn't working. Additionally, I wanted to share that I am using _myvariable in an Update line directly afterwards. In case that sparks some thought. 

    SET _myvariable = replace(_myvariable, '\'', '');
    UPDATE `MyTable` SET NAME=_myvariable WHERE ....

Comment: I have posted above an entire solution in Stored Procedure and it works fine. Can you please post your whole stored procedure because there's possibly something else wrong with your syntax outside of the sample you provided. Ie, are you using `DECLARE` for your variable initially not just `SET`?

Comment: I will try REPLACE("hi th'ere","'", '') also, and update shortly.

Comment: Please see update on initial post, tried all of these, MySQL seems not to replace in my stored proc..... something wrong here?

Comment: From that example your code is wrong (unless your still missing lines?) Ie where is the `DECLARE` statement? Please copy from my Example Stored Procedure use that as a basis I tested it on my server and it works fine

Comment: Actually its because its a Param. Do you have a `IN` line correctly? I've updated my STored Proc Example. it works perfectly on my Server

Comment: YES!!!! You were right I declared in as TEXT instead of VARCHAR, this worked for me!

Comment: @user2137982 great to know, thats why i was asking for your entire Stored Proc syntax including the Param declarations :) Happy days

Answer (score 1):

You can also use two single-quotes which means one literal single-quote in standard SQL.

```
REPLACE("I wan't to be alone", '''', '')
```

FYI, in standard SQL, double-quotes are for delimiting identifiers like table names and column names.  Single quotes are for delimiting strings and dates.  It's a non-standard MySQLism to treat double-quotes as the same as single-quotes.  But I use it in the example above, so I don't have to escape the apostrophe.

---

I also tested:

```
USE test;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Table`;
CREATE TABLE `Table` (
 UID INT PRIMARY KEY,
 NAME TEXT
);
INSERT INTO `Table` VALUES (1, 'foo');

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS q;

DELIMITER !!
CREATE PROCEDURE q(_myparam TEXT, _someotherparam INT)
BEGIN
 SET _myparam = REPLACE(_myparam, '''', '');
 UPDATE `Table` SET NAME=_myparam WHERE UID=_someotherparam;
END!!
DELIMITER ;

CALL q("I wan't to be alone", 1);

SELECT * FROM `Table`;

+-----+--------------------+
| UID | NAME               |
+-----+--------------------+
|   1 | I want to be alone |
+-----+--------------------+
```

It seems to work just fine.  I also tested using VARCHAR(20) for _myparam and that works too.

Comment: Please see update on initial post, tried all of these, MySQL seems not to replace in my stored proc..... something wrong here?